# Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding

Tags: query, quote

Could not resolve the entity from  value binding '{!qotName}'

I am trying to query quote and then update few fields of it. so in apex page I need to show the current value and then have the user change and click on update. but I am getting the following error  Could not resolve the entity from  value binding '{!qotName}'

```
public Quote qotUpdate{get; set;}
public String qotName {get; set;} 
public Date qotExpiration{get;set;}
 public PageReference editQuote(){

 qotUpdate= [SELECT Name,Contact.Phone,Contact.Name,Contact.Email 
             FROM Quote 
             WHERE Id =: '0Q02100000000SV'];
             //WHERE Id =: qot.id];

 //qot.OpportunityId = oppID;
qotName = qot.Name;
qotExpiration = qot.ExpirationDate;

  return Page.updateQuote;


 }

   public PageReference editQuote2(){
        qotUpdate.Name = qotName;
        qotUpdate.ExpirationDate = qotExpiration;
        update qotUpdate;

          return Page.updateQuote;

   }
```

Apex page

```
<apex:outputLabel value="Quote Name" for="QuoteName"/>
            <apex:inputField id="QuoteName" value="{!qotName}"   styleClass="QuoteName" />
            <apex:outputLabel value="Expiration Date" for="ExpirationDate"/>
            <apex:inputField id="ExpirationDate" value="{!qotExpiration}"   styleClass="ExpirationDate" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!editQuote2}" value="Updated"
                              styleClass="btn"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue :** binding class property with apex:inputfield

Here is the [documentation of apex:inputfield component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm)

**Ref :** A merge field that references the Salesforce field that is associated with this inputField. For example, if you want to display an input field for an account's name field, use value="{!account.name}".

**Solutions:**

**So you need to replace your apex:inputfield with apex:inputtext component**

It will be your expected code

```
 <apex:outputLabel value="Quote Name" for="QuoteName"/>
        <apex:inputtext id="QuoteName" value="{!qotName}"   styleClass="QuoteName" />
        <apex:outputLabel value="Expiration Date" for="ExpirationDate"/>
        <apex:inputtext id="ExpirationDate" value="{!qotExpiration}"   styleClass="ExpirationDate" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!editQuote2}" value="Updated"
                          styleClass="btn"/>
```